# Array handling in plsql script

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql

I want to pass an array from shell script to my PL/SQL script as a single argument and then try to access the array elements in PL/SQL script using index. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it. You pass shell array as a space separated string to a stored procedure, then convert it to a collection -  there are numerous ways to do it. In this example I use `string_to_table()` function  of the built-in `apex_util` package.

Here is the procedure(might be function, it's up to you):

```
create or replace procedure p1(p_list in varchar2)
is
  l_array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
begin
  -- convert p_list varchar2 sting to a collection
  l_array := apex_util.string_to_table(p_list, ' ');
  -- iterate through the collection and print each element
  for i in l_array.first..l_array.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_array(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Here we define and pass shell array:

```
array[0] = 'a'
array[1] = 'b'
array[2] = 'c'

sqlplus testlab/testlab@nkpdb <<EOF
set serveroutput on
exec p1('${array[*]}');
EOF
```

Result:

```
SQL> exec p1('a b c');
a
b
c

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that your second code snippet is not a shell script, but an interactive session where `$` denotes the shell prompt (it took me a couple of minutes to figure that out - esp. since `$ array[0]` looks suspiciously like a mis-typed `$array[0]`, but that might just be my stupidity).

Comment: In bash, you can also define the array in a simpler fashion: `array=(a b c)`

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Shell prompt removed, Frank. Yes, there was a typo in the array indexing, thank you.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I need to pass the arguments as command line arguments (not in a procedure) to PL/SQL script where the #(arguments) passed is not certain. How can I handle such situation and receive in PL/SQL script?

Answer (score 1):

Please see below how you can do it in `Oracle`. I used a Oracle defined `collection`(array of varchar). You can create your own collection and pass it in the similar way.

```
--- using oracle defined collection for varchar2 
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure array_list_pass_proc(v_acct5  sys.odcivarchar2list)
as

begin

for i in 1..v_acct5.count -- Passing the array list to loop 
 loop
   --Printing its element
   dbms_output.put_line(v_acct5(i));

 end loop;

end;
/
```

Output:

```
SQL> execute array_list_pass_proc(sys.odcivarchar2list('0001','0002','0003'));
0001
0002
0003

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Please re-read the question - the OP asked about how to pass an array *from a shell script* to PL/SQL, not about how to create a procedure that accepts an array.